# Is it possible to make a runtime db connection and use it in Schema, DB and models without effecting configs?

Tags: laravel

I want to use dynamic databases on runtime without effecting `config/database.php` because of concurrent users.

I have a main db with a table that contains reference to several other dbs. Now at runtime I need to not only connect to those dbs but also may want to run migrations on them.

**I am aware** that this is possible by having a second connection entry in `config.database.connections` but I have a feeling that if two users hit the server at the same time, the physical config file changes may create a conflict.

**I also read** (and also experimented) that you can edit the second connection using below code at runtime:

```
\Config::set('database.connections.mysql2.database', 'somedynamicdb');
DB::purge('mysql2');
```

But I fear that if it persists changes for different users, then it may conflict for concurrent users. And if it does not persist changes, then it wont work for migrations.

I want to understand/know two things specifically:

1. What is the scope of this above code (i.e. `Config::set()` call)? Does it persist over different user calls to the server?
2. If I call migrations using `Artisan::call('migrate')` with a `--database=connectionname` clause, right after I change the db name in `connectionname`, will that use the dynamically set database or the physical config value?

**UPDATE**

Also worth noting that a call to `Artisan::call('migrate')` with a `--database=connectionname`, will make the new connection persist for the rest of your app call.

See here for details:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28253

Comment: I have experimented some more and found out that #2 works, i.e. I can use my dynamically changed connection to run migrations. The question is only that now, that does this connection change/swap persist for a different user call (or we can say a different php process)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config::set` will only apply for the request for which it was set, won't apply to any other requests, and will not persist beyond the request.  If you're not processing a request (e.g. a CLI command) then it won't affect anything beyond the current PHP process.

As for Item #2, if you're invoking from the command line, you can just do `DB_CONNECTION=connectionname php artisan migrate`.  If you need to invoke the artisan command from code, using Config::set is still the right way to go.

Comment: I tested #1 i.e. Config::set() and what you say seems correct. It does not persist. And #2 also seems just like you said, calling it from code makes use of Config::set(), which is awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We use connection created on the fly here all time and works very well. We setup this on Middleware that we included after authentication and is only valid on the user current user request based on login information.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want to do, change connection on the basis of the user token from api call which is processed in the middleware. But I'll have to accept @Chuck Adams answer as it came first and is more descriptive and definite. Thanks again.